# BizTalk - generating schema from Oracle stored proc with table variable argument

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to set up a simple example project in BizTalk that gets changes made to a table in a SQL Server db and updates a copy of that table in an Oracle db.

On the SQL Server side, I have a stored proc named GetItemChanges() that returns a variable number of records.

On the Oracle side, I have a stored proc named Update_Item_Region_Table() designed to take a table of records as a parameter so that it can process all the records returned from GetItemChanges() in one call. It is defined like this:

```
create or replace type itemrec is OBJECT (
        UPC                VARCHAR2(15),
        REGION             VARCHAR2(5),
        LONG_DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(50),
        POS_DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(30),
        POS_DEPT           VARCHAR2(5),
        ITEM_SIZE          VARCHAR2(10),
        ITEM_UOM           VARCHAR2(5),
        BRAND              VARCHAR2(10),
        ITEM_STATUS        VARCHAR2(5),
        TIME_STAMP         VARCHAR2(20),
        COSTEDBYWEIGHT     INTEGER
);

create or replace type tbl_of_rec is table of itemrec;

create or replace PROCEDURE Update_Item_Region_table  ( Item_Data  tbl_of_rec ) 
IS
 errcode integer; 
 errmsg varchar2(4000); 
BEGIN 
   for recIndex in 1 .. Item_Data.COUNT
   loop

   update FL_ITEM_REGION_TEST set
      Region            = Item_Data(recIndex).Region,
      Long_description  = Item_Data(recIndex).Long_description,
      Pos_Description   = Item_Data(recIndex).Pos_description,
      Pos_Dept          = Item_Data(recIndex).Pos_dept,
      Item_Size         = Item_Data(recIndex).Item_Size,
      Item_Uom          = Item_Data(recIndex).Item_Uom,
      Brand             = Item_Data(recIndex).Brand,
      Item_Status       = Item_Data(recIndex).Item_Status,
      Timestamp         = to_date(Item_Data(recIndex).Time_stamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss'),
      CostedByWeight    = Item_Data(recIndex).CostedByWeight
   where
      UPC = Item_Data(recIndex).UPC;

   log_message(Item_Data(recIndex).Region, '', 'Updated item ' || Item_Data(recIndex).UPC || '.');

   end loop;

 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN 
 errcode := SQLCODE(); 
 errmsg := SQLERRM(); 
 log_message('CE', '', 'Error in Update_Item_Region_table(): Code [' || errcode || '], Msg [' || errmsg || ']  ...'); 
END;
```

In my BizTalk project I generate the schemas and binding information for both stored procedures. For the Oracle procedure, I specified a path for the **GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyFilePath** parameter to generate a DLL to contain the definition of the data types. In the Send Port on the server, I put the path to that Types DLL in the **UserAssembliesLoadPath** parameter.

I created a map to translate the GetItemChanges() schema to the Update_Item_Region_Table() schema.

When I run it the data is extracted and transformed fine but causes an exception trying to pass the data to the Oracle proc:

*The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "WcfSendPort_OracleDBBinding_HOST_DATA_Procedure_Custom" with URL "oracledb://dvotst/". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.InvalidOperationException: Custom type mapping for 'HOST_DATA.TBL_OF_REC' is not specified or is invalid.*

So it is apparently not getting the information about the custom data type TBL_OF_REC into the Types DLL.

Any tips on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has trouble with this type of task, my problem was not having all the properties set correctly before generating the schema and binding files.

**GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyFilePath** <- I had this one …

**GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyKeyFilePath** <- I did NOT have this one set … I set it to the same strong named key file I used for the rest of the projects.

Since I had to provide the full path to the DLL in the Send Port, I didn’t think it needed to be in the GAC – but it does - so you have to add it manually since the Deploy process only puts the normal project DLLs into the GAC.

I just ran this command from the Visual Studio command window:

```
gacutil /i [path to the generated user types DLL] /f
```

Comment: It might be beneficial to mark this as the correct answer.